# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils

Tags: java, image, swing, javafx, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting this error every time I attempt to save an image. I can select the image through this code and I press the save button but then I do not find the saved image on my pc in any place instead I obtain the following error. I am using eclipse 2020-9 and java version 15.0.1.
This is the error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils
Any help please?

```
package application;


import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com
 */
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        final Button openButton = new Button("Open Image");

        openButton.setOnAction(
            new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final ActionEvent e) {
                    setExtFilters(fileChooser);
                    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                    if (file != null) {
                        openNewImageWindow(file);
                    }
                }
            });

        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(openButton);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 150);
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy.blogspot.com");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    private void setExtFilters(FileChooser chooser){
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("All Images", "*.*"),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG", "*.png")
        );
    }
            
    private void openNewImageWindow(File file){
        Stage secondStage = new Stage();
        
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu menuFile = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem menuItem_Save = new MenuItem("Save Image");
        menuFile.getItems().addAll(menuItem_Save);
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile);
        
        Label name = new Label(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        
        menuItem_Save.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                fileChooser.setTitle("Save Image");
                
                File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(secondStage);
                if (file != null) {
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imageView.getImage(),
                                null), "png", file);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(
                            Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(name, imageView);
        
        imageView.setFitHeight(400);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 400, 350);
        ((VBox)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(menuBar, vbox);
        
        secondStage.setTitle(file.getName());
        secondStage.setScene(scene);
        secondStage.show();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you added the `javafx.swing` module to your project?

Comment: I added requires javafx.swing to module-info.java but I obtained the same error, then I added it to the VM arguments and it worked. Thank you sooooo much @Slow for your reply